# Why would requests throw an immediate ReadTimeout error?

Tags: python, python-requests

In our production environment (which unfortunately I do not have direct access to), we have some code that looks like this:

```
data = "xml document"
auth = username, password
response = requests.patch(url, data=data, auth=auth,
    headers={'Content-type': 'application/xml'}, timeout=10)
```

In some cases (but not always), we are getting a near-immediate `requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout` exception, much sooner than the `timeout=10` parameter would dictate.

What could cause this?

Is there some actual response that the host could send that would make `requests` throw an immediate timeout exception?

Comment: These type of errors are hard to debug. Can you replicate the behaviour with `curl` command or perhaps other python module?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Unfortunately no, this is happening only in our production environment which I do not have access to.

Comment: whats the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @Kache Sadly I do not have that either.  All I know is that the request throws a  `ReadTimeout` exception.